# "+4" replaced by "$" in AutoHotkey HotString

Tags: autohotkey

I have an AutoHotKey hotstring of the form

```
:*:#hotstring::Some Text and a number 12345 || +49 123456789 || PIN 1234
```

which outputs to

```
Some Text and a number 12345 || $9 123456789 || PIN 1234
```

Why is the "+4" replaced by "$" and how can i prevent that?

Comment: I guess that because '+' in Autohotkey is Shift... So it thinks that you are sending a Shift 4. This is a comment because I'm not sure about that. I'm sure that + is shift but not sure if it interprets it like that and if there is anyway to escape it (it should be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making some research I come up to a sollution, try and tell me if it works please.

It seems like characters used as shift, ctrl, etc need to be escaped. Here is a list:

- **#**: Windows logo key
- **!**: Alt
- **^**: Control
- **+**: Shift
- **&**: To combine custom keys.

The way to escape them is between braces.

```
:*:#hotstring::Some Text and a number 12345 || {+}49 123456789 || PIN 1234
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works. Didn't think of the "+" being interpretted as Shift within the replacement string.

Thanks!